# Creating a SQL Server database - but I get an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to create a SQL Server database, and I get this error

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" arguments error.

I'm also supposed to create a table from a csv, but I'm executing the code in segments first to make sure I'm doing it right.

```
Import-Module -Name sqlps -DisableNameChecking
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(localhost)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "Test_Database")
$db.Create()
Write-Host $db.Name "created" $db.CreateDate
```

Comment: The "local" machine in SQL Server can be specified as `.` (just a dot), `(local)` (with  the parenthesis), or `localhost` (**without** any parens) - your spelling of `(localhost)` is not valid

Comment: this did it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is a issue with server instance name:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(localhost)")
=>
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(".")
```

Comment: So I believe the instance name is UCERTIFY3 and I've replaced localhost with that. I'm pretty much learning SQL for school and I'm definitely not experienced in it.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance is the default instance, then you can use the following:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "Test_Database")
$db.Create()
```

For the named instance, UCERTIFY3, you can use the following syntax:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("SERVERNAME\UCERTIFY3")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "Test_Database")
$db.Create()
```